# Incorrectly removing sprite group enemies in the right order

Tags: python, class, pygame, sprite, collision-detection

I have 2 sprite groups, one for the enemies, and one for the players weapon. An example of how I set up the enemy sprite group... (The weapon sprite group is done the same way)

```
class Bat(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, bat_x, bat_y, bat_image, bat_health, bat_immune, const, dash_counter, dash, dash_time, fly_count, fly_time):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.bat_health = bat_health
        self.bat_immune = bat_immune
        self.const = const
        self.dash_counter = dash_counter
        self.dash = dash
        self.dash_time = dash_time
        self.fly_count = fly_count
        self.fly_time = fly_time
        self.image = bat_image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.image)
        self.rect.topleft = (bat_x, bat_y)
        self.bat_x = bat_x
        self.bat_y = bat_y
    def update(self):
        if pygame.sprite.groupcollide(all_bats, all_sword, False, True):
            self.bat_health -= 1 
        if self.bat_health == 0:
            self.kill()
        ... #Irrelevant
all_bats = pygame.sprite.Group()

def bat_create():
    bat_x = r_x*40
    bat_y = r_y*40
    bat_health = 5
    bat_immune = False
    const = 3
    dash_counter = 0
    dash = False
    dash_time = 0
    fly_count = 0
    fly_time = 0
    new_bat = Bat(bat_x, bat_y, bat_image, bat_health, bat_immune, const, dash_counter, dash, dash_time, fly_count, fly_time)
    all_bats.add(new_bat)
```

When the players weapon hits a bat, regardless of which is being hit, after 5 hits the first bat to spawn is killed. I have no clue why this is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is the issue:

```
def update(self):
    if pygame.sprite.groupcollide(all_bats, all_sword, False, True):
        self.bat_health -= 1
```

`groupcollide` returns a list of collisions. The above code is checking `all_bats` against `all_swords`, so everything Vs everything. And `if ( non-empty-list )` always returns `True`.

So if *any* bat+sword collision is made, this sprite's health is is decreased.  This is probably decreasing *every* bat's `self.bat_health` each time *any* bat collides.  Thus the first item created will reach zero first.

You need to check if "this sprite" is part of the collision.  It's a fairly simply change:

```
def update(self):
    hit_list = pygame.sprite.groupcollide(all_bats, all_sword, False, True):
    if ( self in hit_list ):
        self.bat_health -= 1
```

But it's not efficient to do a `groupcollide` for every bat, during each bat's `update()`.  Perhaps move the `groupcollide` call to somewhere outside the `.update()` function, and just perform these calculations once.  Pass the collision result to the sprite-update function, or suchlike.